# Android socket programming seems like using SSL as default

Tags: android, sockets, ssl

Given this piece of code:

```
 public void run() {
  try{
    try{
       sockMngr.clientSocket=new Socket();
       sockMngr.clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1",1300),7000);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
       System.err.println(e.toString() + " $connection failed.");
    }
    try{
       sockMngr.outs=sockMngr.clientSocket.getOutputStream();
       sockMngr.inps = sockMngr.clientSocket.getInputStream();
    }
    .
    . 
    .
```

(`sockMngr.clientSocket` is a `Socket` object).

and using this `write()` function:

```
    sockMngr.outs.write(buff,0,256);
```

While running Wireshark on the server, I can see only small tcp packets of ACKS, and incomming SSL packets from the Android device sending the data.

as a consequence, I cannot see and analys the transferred data.

Why is that happenning and how can I disable this use of SSL?

thanks.

Comment: I'd bet that Wireshark is calling that an SSL packet based on some heuristic.  As @Remy Lebeau says, Android's socket class doesn't use SSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android's [`Socket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) class DOES NOT use SSL.  You have to use the [`SSLSocket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) class for that.  So something else is going on outside of your code.